# Перевод "Руководства по редактированию" в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация

**Сценарий:**

1. Входим в очередь проверок "Первые вопросы"
2. Выбираем "Править" в списке возможных действий
3. Справа от формы редактора вопроса наблюдаем:

> **Руководство по редактированию**
>
> - Correct minor typos or mistakes
> - Clarify meaning without changing it
> - Add related resources or links
> - Always respect the author’s intent
> - Don’t use edits to reply to the author

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил следующие переводы:

> Correct minor typos or mistakes
> Исправьте опечатки или незначительные ошибки
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17188

> Clarify meaning without changing it
> Уточните сообщение, не меняя его смысл
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17079

> Add related resources or links
> Добавьте связанные ресурсы и ссылки на источники
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17080

> Always respect the author’s intent
> Всегда уважайте замысел автора
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17202

> Don’t use edits to reply to the author
> Не используйте правки в качестве ответа автору
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17187

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.